# Trying to get a snapshot of a variable from firebase gives me an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

### **Problem**

In a social media app I am making with react native and firebase, I am trying to grab the number of comments a post has using the snapshot function of a variable I have saved on my servers, then I am going to add one to this variable when a user adds a new comment. My code to do so is right here:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts').child(this.state.passKey).update({
   comments: firebase.database().ref('posts/'+this.state.passKey).child('comments').snapshot.val() + 1 
})
```

When I actually run this code, I get an error saying:

```
Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined".
Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".","#","$","[", or "["
```

At first I thought this might be that the "this.state.passKey" wasn't actually passing the key, but putting in a key I copied from the server didn't fix the problem.

**My Server**
-[image: A picture of my server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the comments of particular post you should do like this

```
let postId='someId'

postRef=`/posts/${postId}`
firebase.database().ref(postRef).once("value", dataSnapshot => {
comment=dataSnapshot.val().comments
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're expecting this bit of code to query the database:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/'+this.state.passKey).child('comments').snapshot.val() + 1
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.  There's no `snapshot` property on a database [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) object returned by `child()` or `ref()`.

Instead, you'll need to query the database at that reference, then when you're called back with its value, you can apply it elsewhere.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/'+this.state.passKey+'/comments')
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // use the snapshot here
})
```

Comment: using this code: firebase.database().ref('posts/'+this.state.passKey).once('value', function(snapshot) {child.val().comments}) gives me an error, "Can't find variable: child"

Comment: That's because you're using `child` as a variable, but haven't defined it.

Comment: so this is probably a really basic question, but how would I define child to be used in the code like that? Or do I need to use child for what is in my server?